# ROS Answers SE migration: tf2 example?

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Trying to learn ROS, I understand tf is deprecated and tf2 is the currently maintained version. Now the tutorials for tf2 are rather wrong as [stated here](http://answers.ros.org/question/102326/turtle_tf2-package-not-found/) and [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/21) (and as I actually experienced just now). Is there a simple example somewhere I can rely on to know how to listen and broadcast frames?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187433/tf2-example?/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok.... huh...

I just was trying to implement this, when I saw your question. So I will try to help you, or at least show you my solution which seams to work. It is done in C++.

So you need following headers:

```
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
```

Than initialise all variables:

```
tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transform;
```

Ant than the magic line:

```
  try{
    transform = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("base_link", frame_id, ros::Time(0));
  }
  catch (tf2::TransformException ex ){
            ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
  }
```

To this solution I came by searching code of geometry_experimental stack on GitHub.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-24**:
Hello destogl, this is a good to help me start with, thanks for your answer ;)

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2014-07-25**:
There is also code examples now in C++ and Python, please check this pull request: https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/pull/6

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-28**:
Interesting! Thanks a lot , this will help indeed!